# Am I interpreting this relay pin diagram correctly?

Tags: relay, datasheet

I'm using a relay for the first time and am unsure if I'm interpreting the pin diagram given in [the datasheet](http://www.components.omron.com/components/web/PDFLIB.nsf/0/0293ACA6B03161CD86257538007424DB/$file/G5LE_0813.pdf) correctly:

[image]

I know a SPDT relay should have five pins:

```
NO (normally open)
NC (normally closed)
COM (where the power comes in)
Two coil pins (applying voltage across these activates the relay)
```

Here's my guess at what pins are which:

```
1   - COM
2,5 - Coil pins
3   - NO
4   - NC
```

That makes sense to me, but since I've never used a relay before I would really like to double check!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

Anyway if you have doubts:

- connect ohmmeter/continuity tester between 1 and 4 - if it shows zero resistance then this is the NC pin
- do the same for pin 1 and 3. You should get open circuit.
- between any coil pin and switch you should get open circuit.

I always do that, because I get confused with datasheets - top/bottom view.

Apply voltage to pin 2 and 5. Do the same test again. It should show opposite results.

Comment: Am sure that you meant to type "Apply voltage to pin 2" and 5 (coil) :)